# Summing times in Google sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I record my working hours (this is more for me to remind me to stop working than anything else).  For every day, I have three possible shifts - early, normal & late, and I have a formula which will sum up any times put into these columns and give me the daily total hours.

To summarise the duration of time spent working in a day, I use the following formula:  =(C41-B41)+(E41-D41)+12+(G41-F41) which is:
early end time minus early start time
normal end time minus normal start time PLUS 12 hours
late end time minus late start time

Which gives me output like this: [image: working week]

What I cannot seem to achieve is, the ability to sum the daily totals into something which shows me the total hours worked over 1-week.  If I attempt to sum the daily totals together for the example image shown, I get some wild figure such as 1487:25:00 when formatting as 'Duration' or 23:25:00 when formatted as 'Time'!

All my cells where I record the hours worked are formatted as 'Time'

Answer (score 1):

When using arithmetic operations on date values in Google Sheets, it's important to remember that the internal representation of a date is numeric, and understood as the number of days since January 1, 1970.

What follows from that, is that if you want to add 12 hours to a time duration, you should not write "+12" because that will in fact add 12 days. Instead add "+12/24". In other words, try the following formula instead of the one you are using now:

```
=(C41-B41)+(E41-D41)+(12/24+G41-F41)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It makes sense to me that all time values are calculated relevant to Epoch time although I shall admit that I hadn't explicitly considered this in this task.

I tried the change which you suggested but it doesn't give me a correct looking sum value for the total time worked that day. e.g.  two examples
My original formula ->> =(C41-B41)+(E41-D41)+12+(G41-F41) gives me a total of "15:05"
Your suggestion ->> =(C41-B41)+(E41-D41)+(12/24+G41-F41) gives me a total of "03:05:00" as Time or "27:05:00" as Duration.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a copy of your worksheet, indicating also what is the correct expected output.

Comment: Here is a copy of the sheet which shows my the daily sum total (which works, or at least, it provides me with a correct value) and then my manual weekly calculation for total hours worked.  It also shows the formula which you suggested.  

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5xzkiGbMrdkS7twxdE5r03fOeDnnT8vYR_AHlryqWA/edit?usp=sharing

Once again, thank you for taking the time to look at this and provide suggestions.

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you keep adding 12 to every sum. First of all, adding just the number 12 means adding 12 days, not hours, as shown in my answer. This is why you get bogus durations (which accidentally show a "good" result formatted as Time). But you are working on good Time values, you should NOT add 12 hours at all. Just keep the hours in/out as Time, and differences as Duration and it will all work out. Have a look at this copy of your workbook, summing up to the proper value: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QuuUt53gyQtHvTgnb8frYjcWlqM7I1N7jexLtOWgRR4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Wow... I added it for some reason when I first set up the sheet, and being honest, as the daily sum value was correct then I didn't look any further.  Following your comment, I just removed it from the daily sum values, did a sum of the week and set the format to duration... it just works.

I apologise for wasting your time, it was a user error caused by me! *embarrassed*

Thank you for bearing with me and showing me the crux of my issue!

Comment: FYI, I just upvoted your answer but as I have less than 15 rep, it will not show apparently.